# Destructuring in JavaScript 1.7

Tags: javascript, clojure, destructuring

JavaScript 1.7 allows for destructuring:

```
[a, b] = [1, 2] // var a = 1, b = 2;
```

Is there a way to get the rest of the array and head like:
Clojure

```
(let [[head & xs] [1 2 3]] (print head xs)) ; would print: 1 [2 3]
```

Python

```
a, b* = [1, 2, 3]
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Using_JavaScript_1.7

Comment: You mean like Python `a, b* = [1, 2, 3]` or ES6 [rest parameters](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:rest_parameters) `function (a, ...b)`?

Comment: Added Python to my examples assuming that's the correct way to do it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the rest of the array and head in a destructuring assignment?

I don't think so. The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) seems to be supported since FF16 in array literals, but the [harmony proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:spread) does not yet cover destructuring assignments. If it did, it would look like

```
[a, ...b] = [1, 2, 3];
```

***Update***: ES6 does support this syntax, known as the "rest element" in an array destructuring pattern.

So until then, you will need to use a helper function:

```
function deCons(arr) {
    return [arr[0], arr.slice(1)];
}
[a, b] = deCons([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: That works for the answer, but if you needed the first two items instead of [a, b, xs] = [1 , 2 , 3] you'd have to write deDeCons.  Marked correct for the spread operator mentioned.

Comment: FYI, your first example there currently [works in Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20a%2C%20b%3B%0A%0A%5Ba%2C%20...b%5D%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(a%2C%20b)%3B). As ES6 gains wider adoption, it's likely that the need for a helper function like the one in your second example will become less and less necessary.

Comment: @Ajedi32: Yeah, ES6 does support this now. I've edited my answer to reflect this. The question was specifically about JS1.7, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pretty close:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var head = a.shift(); // a is [2, 3] now
```

The gotcha is that it mutates. You can do ´slice()´ before the operation if you want to preserve the original.

This probably isn't the answer you are looking for but it is the simplest way to achieve what you are looking for. You could try to wrap some of that into a function to tidy it up.

Comment: With yield and generators I expect using mutable things will quickly become a rats nest of bugs.  You can tell if you look at whats next in 1.8 :)

Comment: Absolutely. Mutability is just evil. :)